# How to compare generic type to 1

Tags: c#, generics, .net-6.0

The following extension method returns a plural version of `s` only when `value` is not equal to 1.

```
public static string Pluralize<T>(this string s, T value) where T : struct, IComparable
{
    return (value.CompareTo(1) == 0) ? s : s.Pluralize();
}
```

This method works fine when value is type `int`. But if it's a `long`, a `double`, or pretty much any other type, it throws an exception.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object must be of type Double.'

Does anyone know of a generic way to compare `value` to 1 even if `T` is not `int`?

Otherwise, I will just create an overload for each supported type.

Comment: One not so attractive way is to cast to dynamic. Then the overload to pick is not chosen until at runtime when the runtime type is known. For example: `return (dynamic)value == 1 ? "s" : s.Pluralize();` Another way is to use `Convert.ToInt32(value) == 1`, and this will work with most pre-defined types that can "be equal to" `1`. You could use `where T : struct, IConvertible` in that case.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the good old method overloading, it look wierd so that the method can accept DateTime or Guid for instance.

Comment: So what would you expect the result to be if I called it with `Pluralize<TimeSpan>(new TimeSpan(1, 10, 0))`? Ergo, there are only a fixed number of types that actually make sense in this context, so you should just write separate overloads for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using generics you give up most ability to work with the values. Generic constraints give some of that back, but unfortunately there is still no way to constrain types to the integral numeric types, even if that has been talked about for many c# versions now.

If you can guarantee that the method will only be called with types convertible to integers you could use `Convert.ToInt32(value)` to convert it, allowing the result to be compared. But this will fail at runtime for non-numeric types.

You could also use typechecks for each type you want to handle:

```
switch (value)
{
    case float fValue:
        return fValue == 1f ? s : s.Pluralize();
    ...
    default:
        return "fail";
}
```

This would be more code, but would let you handle the default case without resorting to catching exceptions.

Comment: The method-overload approach is quite a bit simpler than a `switch` statement, especially given how simply my method is. But the `Convert.ToDecimal()` does appear to work for all numeric types and can simply be compared to `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions you can apply (3 if you want to risk using preview features).

using `dynamic`:

```
dynamic v = value;
return v == 1 ? s : s.Pluralize();
```

Since the number of possible primitives is exhaustive, you can also simply use a switch or pattern matching, like so:

```
return value switch
{
    1 or 1L or 1UL or 1.0d or 1.0f or 1.0m => s, // covers int, long, ulong, double, float and decimal
    uint x when x == 1 => s,
    short x when x == 1 => s,
    ushort x when x == 1 => s,
    byte x when x == 1 => s,
    sbyte x when x == 1 => s,
    char x when x == 1 => s,
    _ => s.Pluralize()
};
```

(it's unfortunate that there are no literal representations for uint, (u)short, (s)byte and char...)

However, there's also the new '[Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/)' feature on the C#/.Net roadmap that you could leverage for this. Unfortunately it didn't make the cut for .NET 6, but you can already try it (in preview). This would allow you to implement the generic function as follows:

```
static string Pluralize<T>(this string s, INumber<T> value) where T : INumber<T> 
    => value.Equals(T.One) ? s : s.Pluralize();
```

To make this work, you need to add this to your csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.2-mauipre.1.22054.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the generic constraints to IComparable, IComparable, IEquatable and compare two generic values. The values can be class or struct since it implements the interfaces. Int, String, Guid, all works fine.

```
    public bool CompareGenericValues<T>(T value1, T value2)
                where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
    {
        return value1.Equals(value2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar use case which basically required these test inputs:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Pluralize()
{
    var testString = "Unpluralized";
        
    // Integer
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(0));
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(1));
    // String
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize("0"));
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize("1"));
    // Double
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(0.12));
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(1.23));
    // Long (but will still throw an exception if > Int32.MaxValue)
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize((Int64)Int32.MaxValue));
    // IConvertibleToInt Class (Custom interface)
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(new ConvertibleToIntTest(1)));
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(new ConvertibleToIntTest(2)));
    // IConvertible Class (Standard interface)
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(new ConvertibleTest(1)));
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(new ConvertibleTest(1000)));
    // Invalid class T
    Console.WriteLine(testString.Pluralize(new NotConvertibleTest()));
}
```

to return this:
[image: Unit test output]

so we wrote this extension for any T:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Pluralize<T>(this string s, T value)
    {
        int iValue;
        var type = typeof(T).Name;
        if(value is IConvertible conv)
        {
            iValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(conv, typeof(int));
        }
        else if (value is IConvertibleToInt conv2int)
        {
            iValue = conv2int.ToInt(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return $"[{type}] Requires IConvertible or IConvertibleToInt";
        }
        switch (iValue.CompareTo(1))
        {
            case 0:     // Meaning that iValue is 1
                return (value is double dbl) ?
                    $"{type}({dbl}) {s}":
                    $"{type}({iValue}) {s}";
            default:    // Any other value that is not 1
                return Pluralize(s);
        }
        string Pluralize(string str)
        {
            return (value is double dbl) ?
                $"{type}({dbl}) Pluralized" :
                $"{type}({iValue}) Pluralized";
        }
    }
}
```

The generic class T has a choice of implementing IConvertible (a standard interface) or a custom interface like this example:

```
public interface IConvertibleToInt
{
    int ToInt();
}
public class ConvertibleToIntTest : IConvertibleToInt
{
    public ConvertibleToIntTest(int value) => IntegerValue = value;
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public int ToInt() => IntegerValue;
}
```